# Excel or Numbers, How Populate adjacent Column?

Tags: apple-numbers

[image: Table image]

So I feel like this is a pretty simple question, but I cannot for the life of my find the answer, here or elsewhere.

I'm trying to autopopulate a column with custom text. I suppose it would be the row adjacent.

Thought vlookup was the solution, but I'm rusty.

Basically it's financial, if the Description contains, say, "Amazon" or "Subway" I'd like to populate the adjacent cell with "Amazon" or "Online Shopping" or "Subway" or Fast food.

I'm using numbers but assume that excel advice would apply for such a simple (seemingly) task.

Make sense?

Also, hope I formatted the image correctly.

Ok thanks!

Comment: Oh, and the "Categories" column looks like I want it to, but I did that manually.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the sample data I can see a pattern that emerges from these transactions. However, My first thought would be to jump to VBA for Excel but I don't believe that is available for Mac OS.

Vlookup will only work with the *Range_Lookup* set to TRUE which means it will try to find the closest match. This might lead to incorrect matches returned or problems with the requirement for sorting your table array that is being queried.

The only other thing that came to mind which would work for a single query value such as "Amazon" OR "Subway" would be to use a nested formula that checks if that substring is found in the Description column for each cell. This would be something like:

```
    =IF(FIND("Amazon",D1)>0,"Amazon","")
```

The problem with this is that it only checks for one value and it does not have an error handling mechanism so each string that is checked without the word "Amazon" in it will return a **#Value** error in Excel.

Comment: hmm, yeah I tried that and result was:   !http://i.imgur.com/KlGucCW.jpg    !http://i.imgur.com/NET63e0.jpg

Comment: i think i have microsoft excel (uninstalled) on my mac somewhere, but seems like such a simple thing

Comment: @digitalbum the "D1" in the formula would have to be the correct cell reference that you want to check for the string "Amazon" so replace "D1" with whatever cell that is in your example which contains "AMAZON MKTPLACE PMTS AMZN.CO". Also, change the **FIND("Amazon"**... to **FIND("AMAZON"**...

Comment: @digitalbum Sometimes it is the most conceptually simple tasks that have the most complex solutions. What is the scope of the results you are trying to achieve? That is, how many of possible unique strings are you trying to extract from the Description column?

Comment: ain't that the truth.  I mean, for regular, recurring transactions, I'd just like to extract one word for the category.  The description is usually long but will contain something like, "Wal-mart" in it and I'd like the category or label column to be "walmart."  or "Amazon" or "groceries(which I might use instead of "walmart").  So I guess around 10 or 12 strings.  I'm sure there's about 101 ways to do it, many outside of spreadsheet (then putting back into it).

Comment: @digitalbum Okay, so you want to label the transactions based on a string condition being met in the Description field. Conceptually this can be done efficiently with something like a CASE statement and inefficiently with a nested IF statement. Using VBA in Excel you could iterate through the list of possible condition matches checking the Description field and returning the value when matched. However, this would only work if the Description field never contains two matches. That would present a whole different problem.

Comment: If I were to use Excel, would this issue be easier to do?  And sorry it's been awhile.